# Ruby on Rails: Display confirmation message if not includes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In Ruby on Rails, is it possible to display a confirmation message if the user has not entered a string in a text field? I have a form whereby a user enters text in a text field and want to show a confirmation message if they do not enter a certain string. A simple example could be a text field where users can enter items they want to buy from the shop, such as "bread, potatoes, eggs", and so a confirmation message would appear when they click submit saying "You have not entered milk, are you sure you want to proceed?".

I am have the below code working when a user clicks "destroy", and so wonder if this can be developed to work when a user clicks "submit"?

```
 <%= link_to 'Destroy', email_path(email), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: The `data: {confirm: 'Message'}` is assigned to the button when the page is loaded. So you could assign a similar message to a Submit button, but it would always appear. It would not work for a conditional that changes based on user input. The slick way to do it would be on the front end with custom Javascript. To do it with Ruby/Rails, you'll need to test the result on the back end and generate a flash message at the controller level.

Comment: @moveson I am aware that I could do that and that it would always appear, but is it possible to do one based on what the user inputs?

Comment: @BenSmith does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41838032/1536309 if you post your rails form code i can update the example

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without rails using HTML validation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

```
<input pattern=".{3,}" required title="Minimum 3 characters required">
<input pattern=".{8, 15}" required title="Input string should be between 8 - 15 characters">
```

your rails form helpers pass through options to html inputs.